# Insert into existing map a map structure in DynamoDB using Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, nested, amazon-dynamodb

Structure of an item in database is as shown below:

```
{
    "cars": {
        "x": [
            {
                "time": 1485700907669,
                "value": 23
            }
        ]
    },
    "date": 1483214400000,
    "id":"1"
}
```

I have to add a new item "z" of type list to cars like

```
{
    "cars": {
        "x": [
            {
                "time": 1485700907669,
                "value": 23
            }
        ],
        "z": [
            {
                "time": 1485700907669,
                "value": 23
            }
        ]
    },
    "date": 1483214400000,
    "id": "1"
}
```

What would the update expression in Node.js look like if I want to achieve somethings like this?
So far this is what I came up with:
`set #car.#model= list_append(if_not_exists(#car.#model, :empty_list), :value)`

However, if the item does not exist at the time of creation it throws error. Any idea how to do this?

This is the updated parameter I am using, still doesn't work

```
  var params = {
  TableName:table,
  Key:{
      "id": id,
      "date": time.getTime()
  },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  UpdateExpression: 'SET #car.#model = if_not_exists(#car.#model,     
  :empty_list)',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#car': 'cars',
    '#model':"z"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':empty_list': [],
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to update operation in two steps, first create a empty map for the parent since it does not exist in the first place.
So, in my case

```
SET #car= :empty_map
```

where :empty_map = {}

after doing this run the other update expression

```
SET #car.#model = list_append(if_not_exists(#car.#model, :empty_list), :value)
```

where :empty_list=[] and :value= {
                "time": 1485700907669,
                "value": 23
            }

Comment: Glad you worked it out :) What I understood from your original question was that you always had a parent `#car` and you were just trying to add an element to the `#model` list, which might not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Break your update expression apart into two separate expressions:

```
SET #car.#model = if_not_exists(#car.#model, :empty_list) SET #car.#model = list_append(#car.#model, :value)
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it in a single statement?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no.

Comment: I tried this part alone SET #car.#model = if_not_exists(#car.#model, :empty_list) . It doesnt work. Gives error : "The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update",

Comment: Can you please provide the complete working code (including the values for `:empty_list` and `:value`) in order to re-produce the problem?